# Material-UI Datagrid Styling

Tags: material-ui

I'm so confused about how to change the complete row header background color of the DataGrid in the new MUI 5 styling. I think the doc didn't get updated for the new Emotion styling system. Could anyone help me out?

UPDATE:

Ok so I figured out how to actually make a change but I'm using the old makeStyles from Mui 4 is there an alternative to that ?

Here's the code :

```js
import * as React from 'react';

import { DataGrid, frFR } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import { Home } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    col1: '12345 SEIGNEURS, BOULEVARD DES',
    col2: 'TERREBONNE',
    col3: '1',
    col4: '2',
    col5: '3',
    col6: '4',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    col1: '12345 SEIGNEURS, BOULEVARD DES',
    col2: 'TERREBONNE',
    col3: '5',
    col4: '6',
    col5: '7',
    col6: '8',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    col1: '12345 SEIGNEURS, BOULEVARD DES',
    col2: 'TERREBONNE',
    col3: '9',
    col4: '10',
    col5: '11',
    col6: '12',
  },
];

const columns = [
  {
    field: 'col1',
    headerClassName: 'Test',
    headerName: 'Adresse',
    sortable: false,
    width: 375,
  },
  { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Secteur', sortable: false, width: 235 },
  { field: 'col3', flex: 1, headerName: 'Nombre de logement', sortable: false },
  { field: 'col4', flex: 0.5, headerName: 'Déchets', sortable: false },
  { field: 'col5', flex: 0.5, headerName: 'Recyclage', sortable: false },
  { field: 'col6', flex: 0.5, headerName: 'Organique', sortable: false },
];

const theme = createTheme();
const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    borderLeft: 0,
    borderRight: 0,
    borderBottom: 0,
    '& .cold': {
      backgroundColor: '#b9d5ff91',
      color: '#1a3e72',
    },
    '& .hot': {
      backgroundColor: '#ff943975',
      color: '#1a3e72',
    },
  },
}));

export default function DataTable() {
  const handleClick = (params, event) => {};
  const classes = styles();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div sx={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
        <DataGrid
          autoHeight
          className={classes.root}
          getCellClassName={(params) => {
            if (
              params.field === 'col3' ||
              params.field === 'col4' ||
              params.field === 'col5' ||
              params.field === 'col6'
            ) {
              return params.value >= 3 ? 'hot' : 'cold';
            }
            return '';
          }}
          columns={columns}
          disableColumnMenu
          localeText={frFR.components.MuiDataGrid.defaultProps.localeText}
          rows={rows}
          onRowClick={(params, event) => handleClick(params, event)}
        />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```